# Is it possible to retrieve the rotation component of a single video tracking marker?

Tags: python, video, tracking

I am tracking a set of objects through a video and this time I need to extract the rotation component of a marker, in addition to its location.

However, `bpy.data` seems to [only be holding](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_63_7/bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarker.html#bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarker) the normalised locations of the marker in `co`.

Is there some other way to obtain the rotation component of a single marker? I can probably create a proxy of rotation by tracking the relative positions of two markers but retrieving the rotation of a single marker would be really convenient now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [the documentation of a more recent version of Blender](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarker.html#bpy.types.MovieTrackingMarker), you can find a lot more options are available nowadays. There is no rotation, but you do get the coordinates of the search box.