# Motion Tracking. Linking Rotation from Track to Empty

Tags: constraints, tracking, movie-clip-editor

When I do a LocRot track in the Movie Clip Editor and I press the `Link Track to Empty` button, it makes an empty that is linked to the location of the track. How can I make it so it also has the *rotation* as well?

There's got to be a way to do this. It would greatly speed up my workflow!

Thanks!

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Is it possible to retrieve the rotation component of a single video tracking marker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81102/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rotation-component-of-a-single-video-tracking-mar)